# Avoiding usage of Enums for abstraction and dependency injection, struggling at concept

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

So right now I am trying to design a new hire program that grants access to active directory groups, generates documents with their information and location.

Right now I am doing this with an enumeration, with a switch statement that sets the details on the ViewModel like this:

```
                case CaneRidgeSettings.Departments.SCSC:
                Model.ScannerFolder = @"scan1\Supply Chain Service Center\" + Model.UserId;
                Model.ExtensionRanges = "list station 8000 to-ext 8349";
                Model.AdministrativeAssistant = Loader.SCSCAdminAssistant;
                Model.DuoCode = "Franklin TN - 8175";
                Model.PrinterSelectedIndex = (int)CaneRidgeSettings.PrinterGroups.Cane_Ridge_5th_Floor_West;
                return await find.FindNextComputer("800SCSC");
```

The problem I have with this design is that if I ever add more departments to this building, I have to manually update this switch. So I tried a few things around this such as a dictionary, but it didn't seem to bind to a combo-box very well (even when implementing my own INotifyCollectionChanged).

So instead I created an interface that contains this information, for simplicity and length lets just say the interface does this:

```
  public interface IDepartmentInfo
{
    string DepartmentName { get; }
    List<string> ActiveDirectoryGroups { get; }
    string AdministrativeAssistant { get; }
    string Floor { get; }
}
```

I then created a new class that implements this interface

```
public class SCSC : IDepartmentInfo
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; } = "Shared Services";
    public List<string> ActiveDirectoryGroups { get; } = new List<string>() {"Example_AD_GRP","Domain_Users"};
    public string AdministrativeAssistant { get; } = "Lisa_Smith@outlook.com";
    public string Floor { get; } = "5th Floor East";

    public override string ToString() => DepartmentName;
}
```

Then, on my main Building Class I have an observable collection that expects an IDepartmentInfo and initializes those departments

```
   public class CaneRidgeBuilding : IBuilding
{
    public ObservableCollection<IDepartmentInfo> Departments { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<IDepartmentInfo>() {new SCSC(), new ARS()};

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "CaneRidge";
    }
}
```

On my View Model I implemented a few properties, mainly the BuildingSelectedIndex and the DepartmentSelectedIndex.

I also have an IDepartmentInfo property that notifies when it is changed because it is databound to several labels on my UI.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{

    public ObservableCollection<IBuilding> Buildings { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<IBuilding>() { new CaneRidgeBuilding() };
    private ObservableCollection<IDepartmentInfo> _departmentInfos =  new ObservableCollection<IDepartmentInfo>();
    public ObservableCollection<IDepartmentInfo> DepartmentInfos
    {
        get { return _departmentInfos; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _departmentInfos, value); }
    }

    private int _buildingIndex = -1;
    public int BuildingIndex
    {
        get { return _buildingIndex; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _buildingIndex, value);
            SetDepartments();
        }
    }

    private void SetDepartments()
    {
        if (BuildingIndex != -1)
            DepartmentInfos = Buildings[BuildingIndex].Departments;
    }


    private int _departmentIndex = -1;
    public int DepartmentIndex
    {
        get { return _departmentIndex; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _departmentIndex, value);
            LoadDepartmentSettings();
        }
    }


    private IDepartmentInfo _departmentInformation;
    public IDepartmentInfo DepartmentInformation
    {
        get { return _departmentInformation; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _departmentInformation, value); }
    }

    private void LoadDepartmentSettings()
    {
        if (DepartmentIndex != -1)
            DepartmentInformation = DepartmentInfos[DepartmentIndex];
    }

    private string _title = "Prism Application";
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

And it works exactly the way I want it to, however to problem I am running into now is how would I handle dependency injection? If I have 10 departments implementing IDepartmentInfo, how exactly could I pass this to an observable collection?

Because the moment I introduce a new building, if I tell Unity to resolve all IDepartmentInfos, what is going to happen is I'll get every single department even if it doesn't belong to CaneRidge.

If I split the departments to each building, then I run into issues where I can't easily load the departments into the ViewModel, because it is expecting an IDepartmentInfo collection. If I limited it to just one type of collection, then it wouldn't work.

Am I over-complicating things?

Comment: I am not familiar with how you wire unity to WPF, but you could at the point of service registration use reflection to find all descendants of `IDepartmentInfo` in all referenced assemblies, and register them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to inject different buildings and departments, probably not the best way

EDIT: Updated it to use reflection to make it less maintenance

```
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        Container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies()
           .Where(type => typeof(IDepartment).IsAssignableFrom(type)), WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces, WithName.TypeName, WithLifetime.None);

        ObservableCollection<IBuilding> Buildings = new ObservableCollection<IBuilding>()
        {
            Container.Resolve<Building1>(new ParameterOverride("departments",GetDepartmentCollection("Building1"))),
            Container.Resolve<Building2>(new ParameterOverride("departments",GetDepartmentCollection("Building2")))

        };

        Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ObservableCollection<IBuilding>), Buildings,
            new ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager());



    }


    private ObservableCollection<IDepartment> GetDepartmentCollection(string buildingName)
    {
        var departments = new List<IDepartment>();
        foreach (var registration in Container.Registrations.Where( s => s.MappedToType.Namespace.Contains(buildingName)))
        {
            departments.Add((IDepartment)Container.Resolve(registration.MappedToType));
        }
        return new ObservableCollection<IDepartment>(departments);
    }
```

Now I am able to completely eliminate the enumeration and it can be extended in the future without breaking any code or requiring me to change anything.

Comment: From my point of view, this is not a good solution. You've just shifted your problem to another level. Now, if there will be a new building or something, you'll have to change the `ConfigureContainer` method. That's ugly! Changing the data is causing a change in the infrastructure code - a nightmare to maintain!

Comment: I am not sure on the issue with that, this is only the initial root level registration. If I add new buildings or departments, I do not need to update the container because it can be extended upon with a decorator pattern.  Or alternatively, I can use reflection that scans the types from a namespace and resolve all classes that implement the interface. Regardless though, instead of having to rely on dependencies on lower level modules, I only have one place to worry about my dependencies and it makes it way easier to maintain as opposed what I am doing now which is enumerations.

Comment: @Ambidex Your edited solution has way less code (and reflection) than what I suggested (you could lose some reflection in mine, if you'll be registering all classes implementing IDepartmentInfo). On the minus side, you have to follow that convention that departments are under building's namespace, and you're instantiating all departments for all buildings at startup.

Comment: @djomlastic My goal is to make the project simple for a non programmer to update. I am technically not a developer and Work in IT right now. I am self taught for about 5 months now. Eventually, I may consider swapping to a developer position and when that happens the utility I made for automating new hires, a non programmer needs to know how to change things.  I figure doing it this way will make it very easy, as they only have to change properties and not actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea.

**Custom attribute**

Introduce a `BuilingAttribute` so each `IDepartmentInfo` implementation can declare `Type` of the building it belongs to (allow multiple if one department can belong to multiple buildings, I got the idea it can't).

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class BuildingAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type BuildingType { get; private set; }

    public BuildingAttribute(Type buildingType)
    {
        this.BuildingType = buildingType;
    }
}
```

**DepartmentInfo Collection Factory**

An interface that knows how to create a collection of `DepartmentInfo` for each building `Type`.

```
public interface IDepartmentInfoCollectionFactory
{
    void RegisterDepartment<T>(Func<IDepartmentInfo> departmentCreator) where T : class, IBuilding;

    ObservableCollection<IDepartmentInfo> GetDepartments<T>() where T : class, IBuilding;
}
```

And the implementation (will be registered as singleton).

```
public class DepartmentInfoCollectionFactory : IDepartmentInfoCollectionFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<Func<IDepartmentInfo>>> departmentCreators =
        new Dictionary<Type, List<Func<IDepartmentInfo>>>();

    void IDepartmentInfoCollectionFactory.RegisterDepartment<T>(Func<IDepartmentInfo> departmentCreator)
    {
        Type buildingType = typeof(T);

        if (!this.departmentCreators.ContainsKey(buildingType))
            this.departmentCreators.Add(buildingType, new List<Func<IDepartmentInfo>>());

        if (!this.departmentCreators[buildingType].Contains(departmentCreator))
            this.departmentCreators[buildingType].Add(departmentCreator);
    }

    ObservableCollection<IDepartmentInfo> IDepartmentInfoCollectionFactory.GetDepartments<T>()
    {
        Type buildingType = typeof(T);

        if (!this.departmentCreators.ContainsKey(buildingType))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                string.Format("No departments have been registered for {0}.", buildingType.ToString()));

        ObservableCollection<IDepartmentInfo> departmentInfos = new ObservableCollection<IDepartmentInfo>();

        foreach(Func<IDepartmentInfo> creator in this.departmentCreators[buildingType])
        {
            departmentInfos.Add(creator());
        }

        return departmentInfos;
    }
}
```

Configuring the factory, so it knows how to create `IDepartmentInfo` collections.

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    Container.RegisterType<IDepartmentInfoCollectionFactory, DepartmentInfoCollectionFactory>(
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    this.ConfigureDepartmentInfoCollectionFactory(Container.Resolve<IDepartmentInfoCollectionFactory>());
}

private void ConfigureDepartmentInfoCollectionFactory(IDepartmentInfoCollectionFactory factory)
{
    // Types implementing IDepartmentInfo
    var deptInfoTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                                    .GetAssemblies()
                                    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                                    .Where(t => typeof(IDepartmentInfo).IsAssignableFrom(t)  && !t.IsInterface);

    foreach(Type type in deptInfoTypes)
    {
        // Get collection of BuildingAttribute for the type
        var buildingAttributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BuildingAttribute), false)
                                        .OfType<BuildingAttribute>();

        if (buildingAttributes.Count() < 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                string.Format("The type {0} didn't declare BuildingArgument.", type.ToString()));

        var buildingType = buildingAttributes.First().BuildingType;

        if (buildingType == null || !buildingType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IBuilding)))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                string.Format("{0}: BuildingType is not an IBuilding.", type.ToString()));

        var registerMethod = typeof(IDepartmentInfoCollectionFactory).GetMethod("RegisterDepartment")
                                                                .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { buildingType });

        registerMethod.Invoke(factory, new object[]
        {
            new Func<IDepartmentInfo>(() => (IDepartmentInfo)Container.Resolve(type))
        });
    }
}
```

Inject the factory.

```
public class FooBuilding : IBuilding
{
    private IDepartmentInfoCollectionFactory factory;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<IDepartmentInfo> departmentInfos;

    public string Name { get; } = "FooBuilding";

    public ObservableCollection<IDepartmentInfo> DepartmentInfos
    {
        get { return this.departmentInfos; }
    }

    public FooBuilding(IDepartmentInfoCollectionFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.departmentInfos = factory.GetDepartments<FooBuilding>();
    }
}
```

**Adding new department**

It doesn't require any editing, just create new class with the attribute.

```
[Building(typeof(FooBuilding))]
public class BarDepartment : IDepartmentInfo
{
    public string Name { get; } = "Bar department";
}
```